# Lambda expressions numbers divisible by 9 and 3 c#

Tags: c#

I want to write a program that prints from a given array of integers those numbers that are divisible by 3 and 9.I want to use the built-in extension methos and lambda expression.
What I've done:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> l = new List<int>() {18,3,27,42};
        List<int> divBy3 = l.FindAll(x => (x % 9) == 0);
        List<int> divBy9 = l.FindAll(x => (x % 3) == 0);
        if (divBy9 == divBy3)
        {
               foreach (var num in divBy9)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers divisible by 9 and 3 are: {0}",num);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no numbers divisible by 9 and 3.");
        }
    }
```

And the output should be {27,18}.
My output is always the else branch but I don't understand why.I've tried to put in the original array of integers only the values {18,27} and it should verify the equality.In foreach I put to check only in the divBy9 list because I thought that if the 2 lists are equal would be the same thing to check only in one list, but I don't think is good.
What's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing two handles, not the items in the lists they represent. And that's not what you want anyway, you want the intersection:

```
var intersect = divBy9.Intersect(divBy3);  // returns an IEnumerable<int>
```

I don't really know what you're trying to achieve though, the result will always be in `divBy9` because of math reasons.

Also you probably should stop using the obsolete `FindAll`, you can use `Where` to get a clean `Enumerable` without allocating memory for the temporary arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating two different lists and comparing them by reference and even though the lists may contain the same elements (they do not) the references will always be different so your code will select the `else` branch.

As a number divisible by 9 is also divisible by 3 your test seems kind of odd but let us assume that you want to find the numbers divisible by 5 and 9 instead. Then the lambda becomes:

```
x => x%5 == 0 && x%9 == 0
```

E.g.

```
List<int> divBy5And9 = l.FindAll(x => x%5 == 0 && x%9 == 0);
```

This will filter the source list and only pick the elements that are both divisible by 5 and 9.

Comment: `x%3==0` is pointless, because it's implied by `x%9==0` check.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yeah, I guess you are right which is kind of embarrassing as I actually have a degree in math.

Comment: @BradfordDillon according to sample input and output provided by OP he wants numbers dibisible by 9 **and** 3 at the same time - there is `3` in input sequence but not in expected output.

Comment: Hence why I deleted my comment before you posted yours because I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The equality is not doing what you think it's doing. It is comparing the object references, and they are not the same because they are different objects.

You need to take each element in divBy3 and make sure that they are also in divBy9 and vice versa. This is set equality.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the list instances themselves, ie the object references and these will not be the same, as they are different list instances. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) for more details

You want to compare the lists to see if they contain the same values.

There is an extension method which will help you [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> to check only in one list,

Create a dynamic entity to hold the results such as:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 50) // 1,2,3,...50
                        .ToList();

numbers.Where(nmb => (nmb % 3) == 0)  // Give us all numbers divisible by 3.
       .Select(nmb => new
       {
           Number = nmb,
           By3 = true,
           By3And9 = (nmb % 9) == 0 // The ones divisible by 9
       });
```

Result:

[image]